# How can I set background color for some absolute position div?

Tags: html, css

I have a html code:

```
<b>             
 <div class="p" id="p4" style="top:77.0pt;left:179.91301pt;font-family:Times;font-size:13.0pt;">Can</div>
        <div class="p" id="p5" style="top:77.0pt;left:212.02301pt;font-family:Times;font-size:13.0pt;">you</div>
        <div class="p" id="p6" style="top:77.0pt;left:240.53201pt;font-family:Times;font-size:13.0pt;">help</div>
        <div class="p" id="p7" style="top:77.0pt;left:266.14203pt;font-family:Times;font-size:13.0pt;">me?</div>
</b>
```

I want to set background color for `<b>` tag! How can I do that?

Comment: *Off topic* - Please avoid using inline styles... [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: There is nothing positioned, then block div can´t be in inline b. Finally, absolutely positioned elems has zero height.

Comment: Sorry! I have some errors! I edited my post

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vT6hE/

Comment: Thanks, but I have an absolute position parent tag, when I inspect element, size of tag `<b>` is 0px x 0px. So I not work in my case!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v4cNL/

Comment: just a side note, I don't think using `<div>` inside `<b>` is semantically correct. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
b{
  background-color: /*color here*/;
}
```

If you want to do it inline, it works the same way as you've done it for the others:

```
<b style="background-color: /*color here*/;">
```

However, this won't work because `b` is not a `block` element, so the `background-color` property doesn't apply.

To fix this, just have it `display` as `inline-block`.

Stylesheet:

```
b{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: /*color*/;
}
```

Inline:

```
<b style="display: inline-block; background-color: /*color*/;">
```

Doing that will only set the background of the text:

[image]

Alternatively, you can have it fill the entire background of the area that the text fills.

[image]

To do that, just change `inline-block` to `block`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/39fDr/)

Comment: Thanks! But I want class p is in line!

Comment: @user3651839 Just define that: `.p{ display: inline; }` or `<div class="p" id="p5" style="top:77.0pt;left:212.02301pt;font-family:Times;font-size:13.0pt; display: inline;">you</div>`. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/39fDr/2/).

Comment: @user3651839 You forgot the opening `<b>` tag: if you add that, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/v4cNL/2/).

Answer (score -1):

you can set the style in your stylesheet

```
b {
    display:block;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

if you don't want all `<b>` tags to have a red bg, you can give this one a specific class or id.

Since it's absolutely positioned, you will also need to define a width and height.